# Import a class in Scripting java (javax.script)

Tags: java, scripting, java-6, javax.script

I want to import a class that I made in my project, into my script
I did this but it doesn't work:

```
    function doFunction(){
 //Objectif Mensuel
 importPackage(java.lang);
 importClass(KPDataModel.KPData.KPItem); //ERROR HERE, this is my class that I want to import

 KPItem kpItem = kpItemList.get(0);
 System.out.println(kpItem.CellList.get(2).Value);
 System.out.println("-------");
 var proposedMediationSum = Integer.parseInt(kpItemList.get(0).CellList.get(2).Value);
 var refusedMediationSum = Integer.parseInt(kpItemList.get(0).CellList.get(3).Value)
 var totalMediation = proposedMediationSum + refusedMediationSum;

 kpItemList.get(0).CellList.get(4).Value = totalMediation;

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error you get ? I suspect the KPDataModel.KPData.KPItem is not the fully qualified class name or includes all the classes you want to use. i.e. where is kpItemList defined ? Here is a pretty good tutorial http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsimport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, thnx a lot, I found that the problem comes from the import. 
This is what it said in the Oracle website :

> The Packages global variable can be
>   used to access Java packages.
>   Examples: Packages.java.util.Vector,
>   Packages.javax.swing.JFrame. Please
>   note that "java" is a shortcut for
>   "Packages.java". There are equivalent
>   shortcuts for javax, org, edu, com,
>   net prefixes, so pratically all JDK
>   platform classes can be accessed
>   without the "Packages" prefix.

So, to import my class I used : importClass(Packages.KPDataModel.KPData.KPItem);